# Small error on getting JSON from url and echoing the data

Tags: php, arrays, json

So lets say, my url is

```
$priceURL = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=Genuine%20Bloodfeather%20Wings"

$priceArray = file_get_contents($priceURL);
$priceArray = json_decode($priceArray, true);

$lowest = $priceArray['lowest_price'];

echo $lowest;
```

The JSON from the URL is:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$6.63","volume":"169","median_price":"$6.51"}
```

But I received an error of undefined index. Is it because I incorrectly pointing the lowest_price?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Call a `var_dump` on `$priceArray` after running `json_decode` on it.

Comment: Can you check if $priceURL has the right content?

Comment: What is the result of your `file_get_contents()` call? Note that you can only use a url if `fopen` wrappers have been enabled, see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: still error undefined index on lowest_price after var_dump($priceArray);

Comment: Before echo use print_r($priceArray); and chk what rcu getting

Comment: jeroen, I used file_get_contents however this time it doesnt work, does it have anything to do with data that I pointed is invalid?

Comment: this code works for me